# JQuery - Iterate through textboxes and save values to Javascript object

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a button when clicked it iterates through some html elements by class and saves the value to a javascript object. There are 5 html elements per row. How can I save the value of each rows textbox to a corresponding key in the javascript object. The javascript object has the following keys Qty, Length, Breadth, Height, Mass, Description

```js
$.each($('.myClass'), function(index, value) {
  var obj = {
    "Qty": $(this).val(),
    "Length": $(this).val(),
    "Breadth": $(this).val(),
    "Height": $(this).val(),
    "Mass": $(this).val(),
    "Description": $(this).val(),
    "VolWeight": ""
  };
  console.log(obj);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row g-3">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    @*<input id="txtQty" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" type="text" value="1" />*@
    <div class="js-quantity-counter input-group-quantity-counter">
      <input type="number" class="js-result form-control input-group-quantity-counter-control myClass" value="1" id="txtQty4" data-rule-digits="true">

      <div class="input-group-quantity-counter-toggle">
        <a class="js-minus input-group-quantity-counter-btn" href="javascript:;">
          <i class="tio-remove"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="js-plus input-group-quantity-counter-btn" href="javascript:;">
          <i class="tio-add"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-md-2">
    @*<input id="txtLength" class="form-control" placeholder="Length (cm)" type="number" value="1" />*@
    <div class="js-quantity-counter input-group-quantity-counter">
      <input type="number" class="js-result form-control input-group-quantity-counter-control myClass" value="1" id="txtLength4" data-rule-digits="true" max="600" data-msg="Max length 600cm">

      <div class="input-group-quantity-counter-toggle">
        <a class="js-minus input-group-quantity-counter-btn" href="javascript:;">
          <i class="tio-remove"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="js-plus input-group-quantity-counter-btn" href="javascript:;">
          <i class="tio-add"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2">
    @*<input id="txtBreadth" class="form-control" placeholder="Breath (cm)" type="number" value="1" />*@
    <div class="js-quantity-counter input-group-quantity-counter w-100">
      <input type="number" class="js-result form-control input-group-quantity-counter-control myClass" value="1" id="txtBreadth4" data-rule-digits="true" max="250" data-msg="Max length 250cm">

      <div class="input-group-quantity-counter-toggle">
        <a class="js-minus input-group-quantity-counter-btn" href="javascript:;">
          <i class="tio-remove"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="js-plus input-group-quantity-counter-btn" href="javascript:;">
          <i class="tio-add"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2">
    @*<input id="txtHeight" class="form-control" placeholder="Height (cm)" type="number" value="1" />*@
    <div class="js-quantity-counter input-group-quantity-counter w-100">
      <input type="number" class="js-result form-control input-group-quantity-counter-control myClass" value="1" id="txtHeight4" data-rule-digits="true" max="250" data-msg="Max length 250cm">

      <div class="input-group-quantity-counter-toggle">
        <a class="js-minus input-group-quantity-counter-btn" href="javascript:;">
          <i class="tio-remove"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="js-plus input-group-quantity-counter-btn" href="javascript:;">
          <i class="tio-add"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2">
    @*<input id="txtMass" class="form-control" placeholder="Mass (kg)" type="number" value="1" />*@
    <div class="js-quantity-counter input-group-quantity-counter">
      <input type="number" class="js-result form-control input-group-quantity-counter-control myClass" value="1" id="txtMass4" data-rule-digits="true">

      <div class="input-group-quantity-counter-toggle">
        <a class="js-minus input-group-quantity-counter-btn" href="javascript:;">
          <i class="tio-remove"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="js-plus input-group-quantity-counter-btn" href="javascript:;">
          <i class="tio-add"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2">
    <select class="js-select2-custom custom-select myClass" size="1" id="txtDescription4" style="opacity: 0;" data-hs-select2-options='{ "minimumResultsForSearch": "Infinity","placeholder": "Load Type" }'>
      <option value="Boxes">Boxes</option>
      <option value="Envelop">Envelop</option>
      <option value="Pallet">Pallet</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your desired result is? A single object with keys for each row, that each contains the corresponding row object you've defined?

Comment: @Sean exactly as you mentioned, A single object with keys for each row, that each contains the corresponding row object you've defined

Comment: Still not really clear what you want. Do you want to collect the data of _one_ single row, or that of multiple rows in one go?

Comment: @CBroe I want to collect the data for multiple rows

Comment: Then what _exactly_ is the result supposed to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an object per row, not an object per input.

Loop over the rows and create a new object for each row instance, then loop over the inputs in that row to set the key/values. A `name` on each input will help for the keys

Following uses `map()` to return an array of objects

```js
const res = $('.row').map(function(){
    // object for this row
    const obj = {};
    // loop over relevant inputs in this row
    $(this).find('input.myClass').each(function(i,el){
         // set key/value of object for this input         
         obj[el.name] = el.value;
    })
    return obj
}).get()

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
 Qty <input name="Qty" type="text" class="myClass" value="3">
 Length  <input name="Length" type="text" class="myClass" value="4">
</div>
<div class="row">
 Qty <input name="Qty" type="text" class="myClass" value="5">
 Length  <input name="Length" type="text" class="myClass" value="6">
</div>
```

Comment: wonderful, how can I get a dropdowns value

Comment: If you mean a `<select>` it also has `value` as does a textarea

Comment: yes <select> $(this).find('input.myClass').each(function(i,el) is using input only

Comment: OK, add selector in `find()` for the select also . If it has same class can just do `find('.myClass')`, or `find('input.myClass, select.someClass')`. Lots of ways to target them